# Is $T : F \to \textsf{C}([a,b])$ defined by $Tf = f''$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

$\textsf{C}([a,b])$ is a normed space with
$$\| f \| := \sup \{ |f(x)| :\, a \leq x \leq b \}.$$
Let $$F := \{ f \in \textsf{C}([a,b]) :\, f'' \textrm{ is continuous and } f(a)=f(b)=0 \}.$$
Is $T : F \to \textsf{C}([a,b])$ defined by $Tf = f''$ continuous?

Comment: No, this is not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = \sin ( { 2 \pi n x \over b-a})$, then $\|f_n\| = 1$, but
$\|f_n''\| = ({ 2 \pi n x \over b-a})^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell the topology or norm on $F$. If it is $|f|_F=|f|_\sup+|f'|_\sup$, which is correct in the sense that it makes $F$ complete, then, yes, the differentiation map from $F$ to $C[a,b]$ is continuous in the respective topologies.

If, instead, you use the $C[a,b]$ sup-norm topology on $F$, then the differentiation map $F\to C[a,b]$ is *not* continuous.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. Norms for F and C[a,b] are same. Are you sure that this is not continuous. I've proven that T(f)=f'' (second derivative) is a bijective linear function with continuous inverse. But I can show neither T is bounded (so continuous) nor not.

Comment: @fenerli: Those observations would make an excellent contribution to your Question.  In its present form it is very light on context.